# MVCSiteMapProvider some nodes match, others do not

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, url-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using `MvcSiteMapProvider` to generate breadcrumbs and I am having trouble matching nodes with a new feature. We use MVC5 areas and are using the latest `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5` libraries. We are using `i18n` with `Resx` files, our `title` attribute being keys. Our page URLs don't change after release, so use the standard XML config.

We use MVC5 attribute based routing.

The `List` action is the default action for both the Home controller and the area, so is on the `Store/` route. It works fine, the match is made.

The `Search` action `Store/Search` route *does not* match a node.

**Configuration**

```
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode controller="Dashboard" action="Index" title="Foobar" key="Bar">

    <!-- quite a large file -->

    <mvcSiteMapNode area="Store" controller="Home" action="List" title="SiteMap_DocumentStore_Home_List" preservedRouteParameters="page, itemsPerPage, msg">
      <mvcSiteMapNode area="Store" controller="Home" action="Search" title="SiteMap_DocumentStore_Search" preservedRouteParameters="tags, page"/>

      <!-- snip extra entries -->
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

I appreciate that I can remove attributes `area` and `controller` from the `mvcSiteMapNode` children of `List`. I've left them in here for completeness.

**Home Controller**

```
[RouteArea("Store")]
[Route("{action=list}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  [Route("{page?}/{itemsPerPage?}")]
  public ActionResult List(int page = 1, int itemsPerPage = -1, string msg = "")
  {}

  [Route("Search/{tags?}/{page?}")]
    public ActionResult Search(string tags = "", int page = 1)
  {}
}
```

**Investigation**

I have a feeling that it is something to do with the MVC Route for the `List` action being *empty*. If I change the route of `List` to:

```
[Route("List/{page?}/{itemsPerPage?}")]
public ActionResult List(int page = 1, int itemsPerPage = -1, string msg = "")
{}
```

Then the Search node will then match, as will its siblings (that I snipped out)

**Edit - Simplify the routing**

I have removed the default route for the controller `[Route("{action=list}")]`. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue #1:

Per [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#route-areas):

> ### Default Route
>
> You can also apply the [Route] attribute on the controller level, capturing the action as a parameter. That route would then be applied on all actions in the controller, ***unless a specific [Route] has been defined on a specific action, overriding the default set on the controller***.

In your case, the default controller-level route will be completely ignored because in each case you have a route at the action level that is overriding it.

### Issue #2:

I looked into why it is "not matching" by starting a new MVC 5 project in VS 2015 and adding an area and the rest of your config. For awhile I was perplexed as to why it wasn't working.

Then I discovered that the scaffolding wires up a different layout page for each Area in `/Area/<area name>/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Store/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I changed it to use the shared `ViewStart.cshtml` file, and then it showed the breadcrumb trail.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

### Issue #3:

Also, you have an issue with your preserved route parameters. Since they are always derived from the current request, the inner request must always provide all of the parameters of its ancestors. Furthermore, the parameters must not have a different meaning between parent and child, so for example `page` must refer to the same page for both `List` and `Search`. In other words, each key name must be unique within its ancestry.

If they are the same, you can fix this by simply adding the additional parameter to the Search URL.

```
[Route("Search/{page?}/{itemsPerPage?}/{tags?}")]
```

Otherwise you should give each `page` parameter a different name.

See [How to make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](https://web.archive.org/web/20160425143429/http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) and the demos included for guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't see how this answers my question. If use a route such as `[Route("List/{page?}/{itemsPerPage?}")]` then `[Route("Search/{tags?}/{page?}")]` works also. If I use an empty action for the List `[Route("{page?}/{itemsPerPage?}")]` then it doesn't. Route parameters have no effect.

Comment: When using Attribute Routing, the action is *never* empty. It is derived from the action method. The route `[Route("{page?}/{itemsPerPage?}")]` requires the "action" part of the URL to be missing in order to work, but it still uses the action name from the action it is declared on in the route values dictionary. This route will match *any* URL with 2 segments because placeholders can be anything. Whether it works or not depends on whether you have any other routes that match a URL with 2 segments that are registered before this route - in .NET routing the first match always wins.

Comment: Wonderful, that certainly makes sense. I still don't understand why the SiteMapNode doesn't match against my Search route. Sorry for being so slow!

Comment: See my edit above. I have verified the node matches in this case, but be sure you have `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()` declared in the right layout page. Also, see [this demo](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_SO_AttributeRouteAreas) to see it matching the nodes in this case (but note the demo doesn't address issue #3 above).